# str_replace domains without listing them all

Tags: javascript

So I am pretty new to javascript, but I have a chat on my website, and I use this code to replace listed urls to *

```
$cens2=array(
              'ninjackpot.com','','','','','','','','','','','',
             );

                foreach($cens2 as $c)

                $dbname=str_ireplace($cens2, '*', $dbname);
```

How do I replace all url's without listing them all, like I did with ninjackpot.com.
I only want to replace the url's in $dbname, not the whole other "non-url" text it contains

Comment: Is that php or js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to what you really need. But if i understand, this is it :

Your text with many url :

```
var text = "hello my text http://google.com can contain http://facebook.com multiple url like http://amazon.com";
```

Use regular expression to match every url on your text and replace it by "*".
This is not my Regex, I found it, i'm not good for create it, it's maybe not optimize for match every url.

```
var text_no_url = text.replace(/https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g, "*");


console.log(text_no_url);
```

Output :

```
hello my text * can contain * multiple url like *
```

[JSFiddle for live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6r6c1hpt/)

Comment: Just what I wanted, Thanks!